# Build in R a list of vectors from two variables in a table

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I need to build a list of coordinates from two variables, but I can't figure out how to do this in R

This data contains 2 variables lat and long

```
data_table <- structure(list(lat = c(1.2, 1.54),
                     long = c(4.23, 4.29)),
                row.names = c(NA,-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

lat   long
---------
1.2   4.23
1.54  4.29
```

and I would like to constitute a couple of data in a list of vectors, to obtain the following structure:

```
 list(
      c(1.2, 4.23),
      c(1.54, 4.29)
    )
```

Expected output:

```
[[1]]
[1]  1.2 4.23

[[2]]
[1]  1.54 4.29
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `asplit`:

```r
asplit(data_table, 1)
```

output

```r
# [[1]]
#  lat long 
# 1.20 4.23 
# 
# [[2]]
#  lat long 
# 1.54 4.29
```

Comment: How can remove "lat" and "long"? I edited my post with the expected output

Answer (score 2):

One

```
> as.list(as.data.frame(t(data_table)))
$V1
[1] 1.20 4.23

$V2
[1] 1.54 4.29
```

Comment: Assuming OP has `data.table` loaded already you can replace `as.data.frame(t(data_table))` with more efficient `transpose(data_table)`.